# OpenGL SuperBible 6 first example error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I am trying to write and run the first example in the book "OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition", but I can't get it to work. I get the error:

```
fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'sb6.h':
No such file or directory
```

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express so I tried fixing this by including as an external resource the folder *include* where the sb6.h file is located adding *"sb6/include"* to:

```
Project | Properties | VC++ folders | Include files folders
```

But that didn't work and now the error is:

```
\include\sb6.h(69): fatal error C1083:
No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'glfw.h':
No such file or directory
```

I tried solving this by adding the folder *include/GL* in the same way that the folder *include*, but the same error message is thrown.

Just in case you need it, this is my code:

```
#include <sb6.h>

class my_application : public sb6::application {
public:
    void render(double currentTime) {
        static const GLclampf red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }
};

DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

Answer (score 3):

After trying a lot of things, I went to the working examples' configuration and looked for differences to my configurations. I ended up modifying 3 things:

**1.Project | Properties | VC++ Directories | Include Directories**
  Added two folders: *sb6/include* and *sb6\extern\glfw-2.7.6\include*.

**2.Project | Properties | VC++ Directories | Library Directories**
Added one folder: *sb6/lib*.

**3.Project | Properties | C/C++ | Preprocesor | Preprocesor Definitions**
Added three definitions:

```
WIN32
NDEBUG
_WINDOWS
```

---

*sb6 folder being the folder where examples are.*

After this, I am able to run my_application (from the question post) in Release and Debug mode.  Even so, it throws a lot of messages in debug output: [Debug output.(pastebin.com)](http://pastebin.com/fvjB5HmV) maybe someone knows how to avoid this?

Comment: Those are normal. Don't worry about them. Based on your debug output, everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the [GLFW library](http://www.glfw.org/) too and add its include and library paths to your project, and link with its library.

The older versions of GLFW (pre-3) is source and binary forms [are available from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/files/glfw/).

Comment: Hi, thanks but I just downloaded GLFW 3.0.4, but in the include folder there is only these files: _glfw3.h_ and _glfw3native.h_ maybe it's not the correct version? Though I don't seem to be able to find previous versions of GLFW.

Comment: You do need an older version and they have a GitHub repository, so you can get an older version from GitHub, build it yourself and then use that. Or, you can change the SB6 sample code to use GLFW3; I don't know how hard it would be, but it could be just a few renames and such.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the OpenGL SuperBible website probably lets you download the sample code *along with any needed libraries*. Have you checked there?

Comment: @sempiedram: Older versions are available on Sourceforge (I've updated the answer.)

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded an older version, but how to build it? I have built it from the file _glfw-legacy-master\support\msvc100\GLFW.sln_ with Visual C++, now what?